# Informatica Cloud - File Name with Date

Tags: informatica-cloud, iics-di

I have oracle (12c) table with column names from_dt, to_dt.

```
create table param ( name varchar2(10), from_dt date, to_date date);
insert into param values ('Test', '03-FEB-2022', '04-FEB-2022');
```

I want to append the to_dt value (in format 'YYYYMMDD') from the Oracle table and append to the file name.

i want the file name like ABC_20220204.txt.

Could please let me know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

in target object properties - select Use a Dynamic File Name and enter the file name expression in the expression editor.
first select dynamic file name.
Then, pls use below expression transformation -

```
'ABC_'||To_Char(to_date,'YYYYMMDD')||'.txt'
```

Here is a sample example for your reference.
[image: sample]

Comment: I don't think this is a valid anwser, that option to use a Dynamic File Name, doesn't appear to be available anymore. Working with Informatica is such a big headache.